# Using selenium on a webapp that builds its DOM elements through Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I recently installed the stable-diffusion webUI on my system, and I have plans on creating a wrapper program focusing on trying out different prompt generation techniques with different parameters (sampling methods, steps, ect.).

To do this, I originally looked into making REST API calls, but it seems the webUI is pretty integral to the generation process, so I shifted my efforts to using (Python) selenium to interact with the UI in order to generate the images. The program is running locally on my system, and I can reach the App via localhost:7860

But I must admit that my knowledge of Javascript is very... 2009. And contemporary Apps are quite confusing to me.

Using Firefox dev tools, I inspected the WebUI page to find the ID of the div containing the textbox that accepts the prompt from the user:

[image]

Then I attempted to use the following Python code to get the div element using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://localhost:7860/")
div_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'txt2img_prompt')
```

But I am met with a NoSuchElementException

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="txt2img_prompt"]
```

I then checked the Source that selenium is picking up, and it indeed does not contain the div, but rather some minimal HTML elements, and a bunch of script tags which presumably build the page on load.

So I guess my question is, how do I get the DOM elements I see from the devtools inspect action into selenium so I can start interacting with the webpage programmatically (Clicking, typing, ect.)

The source picked up by selenium is too long for me to post here... But I can get away with posting a screenshot of the first page.

[image]

The rest is just script tags with JS, until at the very bottom, there is one more small portion of html:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: first you may try to use `time.sleep()` and wait few seconds because JavaScript may need time to create objects. Later you can use [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) for this.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: @furas as I mentioned, I wasn't able to post the code as text as it put me over the characterlimit. There are also around 1300 lines of Javascript under the html, so if there is a way for me to link the full html file to this post, that would probably be best.

As for the sleep, I did attempt that, and the source still seems unchanged. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: don't send full code but code which you show on images. What do you see in browser's window?  If you don't close browser in code then you could open DevTools to see what you really get in HTML. And maybe you should use longer sleep

Comment: BTW: in question you could add link to `stable-diffusion webUI`

Comment: It's either in an iframe or you're not waiting long enough

Comment: @pguardiario I have put in waits up to 2 mins, and I see the page fully loaded and usable, so an iframe seems to be the right track. Searching the source, I see the only mention of iframe is in a the url of a script tag: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/4.3.1/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script> ... But I don't actually see any iframe tags in the html

Answer (score 0):

So, find the path of things using chrome inspect and right-click on the thing you want, and copy using the JS path

[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niPZh.png)

And then use the JS path to find the element you want. In JS I used this and it worked:

```
//find the txt2img_prompt
const textBox = await driver.executeScript(
    "return document.querySelector(\"body > gradio-app\").shadowRoot.querySelector(\"#txt2img_prompt > label > textarea\");"
);

// Type text into the textbox
await textBox.sendKeys('Hello, world!');
```